# Controller exclusion does not work

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have 2 artifacts which are included to main project. The first one contains package "`com.parent.controller`". The second - "`com.child.controller`".

Each package contains one contoller - `ParentController` and `ChildContoller`, respectively. Both of them have the same RequestMapping (for example just "`/abc`"). Also I have included exlude filter for `ParentController`. But in any case I have an exception:
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping`. How to fix it?

```
@SpringBootConfiguration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.parent", "com.child"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.parent", "com.child"}, excludeFilters = {
    @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.CUSTOM, classes = TypeExcludeFilter.class),
    @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.CUSTOM, classes = AutoConfigurationExcludeFilter.class),
    @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern = "com\\.parent\\..*Controller"),
    @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = ParentController.class)
})
```

**UPD 1**. The packages hierarchy:

```
- com
  - parent
    - controller
      - ParentController
    - service
    - dao
    - entity
  - child
    - controller
      - ChildController
    - service
    - dao
    - entity
```

Comment: What's the reason of having two controllers with same mapping?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar, The parent artifact is external unmodifiable library. And I would like to override some mappings from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't scan `com.parent` root package. Scan each sub package separately, like `com.parent.entities`.  Won't need the exclude then.
If that doesn't work, post the parent and child package hierarchy for specific instructions.